# Why do some btree diagrams have multiple nodes at the same level?

Tags: b-tree

Why do some diagrams have no value for each node and instead have 2 values? What are they trying to represent?

The second diagram makes sense if 8 has a left and right node of 6 and 7. I don't understand why in the first diagram 100 has 2 left and 2 right nodes.

What am I missing here?

[image]
[image]

Comment: The root node `100` in the first diagram has only two child nodes. The one to the left is the node `35 65` (that is one node), the other one is `130 180` (again, one node). Why do you think that the root node has four children?

Comment: Not all entries will be full? See this handy [B-Tree Visualization](https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/BTree.html).

Comment: Maybe it is necessary to say that B-tree and binary tree are two different data structures. In a B-tree a single node can have multiple keys (what you call "nodes"). A box in the first diagram is a node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't understand why in the first diagram 100 has 2 left and 2 right nodes.

First of all, a B-tree is not a binary (search) tree: a node in a B-tree is designed to allow for more than one key up to a fixed maximum. In the first image, a box represents a *single* node with potentially multiple keys. In the second image there are separation lines between the keys, but it is the same principle. So in usual terminology the first diagram shows a root node with only two children, not four.

> Why do some diagrams have no value for each node and instead have 2 values?

You are referring to the *keys* contained within a single node. Each node has a fixed number of slots that can be occupied by keys, but this is dynamic. During the lifetime of a node, it may have a varying number of keys, but within certain limits.

The images depict B-trees of order 3 (using [Knuth's definition of order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree#Definition), which is the maximum branching factor).